# Android: MediaMetadataRetriver fails for ID3v2

Tags: android, mp3, metadata, id3, id3v2

I'm part of a group developing a media player for Android (API 11 and up) and we're having a rather vexing problems with MediaMetadataRetriever. It works fine on the Android 4.2.2 phone and various emulators we use for testing, but not on the 4.1 phone: it only returns "null" for all attempts to extracts metadata, using the same code that worked on all other devices. The problem only arises with mp3s that lack ID3v1 tags (but do have ID3v2).

```
this.artist=reader.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
```

Both phones are Samsung devices. We know that the paths given are valid, since they work for our playback function. MediaMetadataRetriver was introduced in 3.0, so the Android version difference shouldn't be relevant (but might be anyway). I have been searching and found absolutely nothing even similar to this problem, does anyone know what might cause this?